# Edittext cursor pointer goes out of view

Tags: android

I have used an Edittext whose "maxlines" is set to 1. When I enter some large text, a certain portion of the text is not visible. So I use the cursor pointer (blue color which appears on single tap on edittext) to scroll through the text. But when I try to use it, it goes beyond the view instead of showing the text which is hidden.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Set below properties of your Edittext, it will solve your problem.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html states the following

```
        android:maxLength   
        setFilters(InputFilter) 
        Set an input filter to constrain the text length to the specified number.
```

You can use this to specify the length of the EditText input

or you want the Text to be wider than the view then you can use

```
        android:scrollHorizontally  
        setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)   
        Whether the text is allowed to be wider than the view (and therefore can be scrolled horizontally).
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you mean, my answer is based on what I understand of your question:

Try using the following lines of code in your XML:

```
    android:paddingRight="08dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="08dp"
```